# Can row space be understood as a set of linear combination that represents a single solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I doubt that I understand row space. I'm not sure what it means to have a solution in the row space of matrix $A$. This seems to mean that the linear combination of the rows forms a solution of $Ax=b$.

Is it only indirectly understood by the fact that it is an orthogonal complement of a null space? Can I say that the coefficient of linear combination has no other meaning when solution is in row space?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, every vector is in the row space. Where you started is perhaps that even for non-invertible, non-square matrices, there is always a unique solution $x$ *in the row space* of $Ax=b$ whenever $b$ is in the column space.

Comment: Yes you can since $Ax = b \implies A^{-1} A x = A^{-1}b \implies x = A^{-1}b$

Comment: You’re trying to write $A^{-1}x = b$? Then $x = Ab$.

Comment: @Bal, are you assuming $A$ is invertible?

Comment: @GerryMyerson initially the questionnaire assumed $A$ to be invertible.  Now he has edited the question. I added an answer check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Singular Value Decomposition (SVD): $A=U\Lambda V^H$, with $U = [u_1,...,u_n]$ and $V = [v_1,...,v_n]$ and $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix, From this decomposition we have that:
Column Space of $A = C_A = \{u_i : \lambda_i \neq 0\}$ and the Row Space of $A = R_A = \{v^H_i : \lambda_i \neq 0\}$.

Now write $Ax=b \implies U \Lambda V^H x = b$.
$Ax$ will change only based on $\{i:(V^H x)_i \neq 0, \lambda_i \neq 0\}$.

Hence let $\lambda_i \neq 0$ and $(V^H x)_i \neq 0 \iff v_i^H x \neq 0 \implies x \in R^*_A = \langle \{v_i : \lambda_i \neq 0\} \rangle$ for one particular solution. The Solution space is $x_R+\langle\{v_i : \lambda_i = 0\} \rangle$ where $x_R \in \langle\{v_i : \lambda_i \neq 0\} \rangle$. So there does exist a solution $x_R$ in the space spanned by rows of $A$ after conjugation but you can add a vector from $\langle\{v_i : \lambda_i = 0\}\rangle$ and it still remains a solution but does not belong to row space of $A$.

Short Answer:
There exists a solution in row space (after conjugation) of $A$ but not all of the solutions are in row space of $A$.